# React Native: "setBackgroundColor is only available on android" warning on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Like this:

[image]
How can remove this warning?

Answer (score 2):

As the warning states, setBackgroundColor style can only be applicable for Android version only.

You can solve this warning by specifying the style to apply only for Android version using below snippet.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native' // on top of the file

style={{ setBackgroundColor : Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'blue' : null }} // style of the component
```

If you wish to disable all yellow warnings. Put below snippet in app.js after the imports and before class initialization.

```
//Disable warnings in both Android and IOS
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Comment: Please provide correction instead of disable all warnings.

Comment: I read the question as how to remove the warning. I will edit my answer.

Comment: FYI this is not styling issue but https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#setbackgroundcolor which only available in android so he should put this for android only.

Comment: I believe you want to use `Platform.OS` instead of `Platform` in the conditional now. Could be an update.